# Git silently merges as updates what should be conflicts

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Simplified, this is what happened to us:

- Start with this file on `master`:

  ```
  class SomeClass {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Create branch `featureA` off `master.
- On `featureA`, change file to:

  ```
  class SomeClass {
      ...
  }

  extension SomeClass {
      // implement feature A
  }
  ```
- Create branch `featureB` off `master.
- On `featureB`, change file to:

  ```
  class SomeClass {
      ...
  }

  class OtherClass {
      // implement feature B
  }
  ```
- Merge `featureB` into `master`.
- Merge `featureA` into `master`.

What we *expect* is:

```
class SomeClass {
    ...
}

extension SomeClass {
    // implement feature A
}

class OtherClass {
    // implement feature B
}
```

or the two additions in reverse order, that's fair.
Realistically, Git should probably report a conflict: it has no knowledge about semantics, and the two "simultaneous" changes can not be reconciled.

What we *get* is:

```
class SomeClass {
    ...
}

class OtherClass {
    // implement feature B
}
```

without a conflict. That is, the later commit (that was merged before the other) wins out, silently.

Can this be prevented? How?

*Note:* If I try this in a clean repo with the steps above, I get a merge conflict in the last step. So either the issue was rooted in something else we did on the repo; hints appreciated, I don't see what could have affected things. Or the problem is the diff algorithm being tripped up by more complicated code; in the production Swift code, we had two extensions on one side, and an enum with nested types on the other side.

Comment: Were any [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) used?

Comment: @MarcinArmatys As far as I'm aware, only the default `git merge` has been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cross-testing with the same attempted merge:

- On Ubuntu with Git 2.7.4 and Meld 3.14.2, I see conflicts with `git merge` and `git merge -s patience`.
- On Mac with Git 2.11.0 and Meld 3.16.0, I see *no* conflicts with either merge command.

  Instead, there's

  ```
  ==== BASE ====
  }
  ==== BASE ====
  ```

  at the end of the file, so I think Meld is not parsing the diff correctly here.
- On the same Mac and during the same merge, the diff viewer in AppCode 2017.3 shows a conflict.

It seems as if that version of Meld has trouble parsing some diffs. It didn't show me the conflict, so I didn't fix it properly before marking it as resolved.

Nota bene: reproducing this apparently needs more "matching" lines; the small example from my question doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to consider in a mis-merge case that you can prove was not human error is that Git's merge uses Git's diffs as input. If the diffs synchronize on trivial items, such as close brace lines that happen to have the right indentation, Git can put the merge results in places that are well-indented and hence *compile*, but are semantically ill-suited and hence do not *function*.

If you convince Git not to synchronize on trivia, it's more likely to detect actual conflicts.  You can do this by changing the diff algorithm used at merge time.  You can try choosing the `patience` or `histogram` algorithms, using `-X patience` or `-X histogram`.  For a (brief) discussion of the details, see what's currently the end of chapter 3 (p. 65) of my not-making-much-progress-on-weekends [book](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know different diff algorithms are available to choose from. Unfortunately, none of them seems to identify the difference correctly. And, honestly, I don't know how a line-based diff *could*. I'm not sure how `git merge` goes from a diff (which shows, well, differences) to deciding what's an edit and what's a conflict.

Comment: Internally, since Git has the merge base version of the file plus both branch tip versions of the file, it merely has to note the line-span range of each diff. Call the two sides L (left/local) and R (right/remote). Suppose we sort the union-ed diffs by starting line number. The "current" change (from either L or R) spans some line range [K..K+N) of the base file. If the "next" diff, from whichever one this *isn't* from, also spans the same range, there is a conflict. Otherwise apply this change and move on to the actual next (which may be from the same L/R rather than the other).

Comment: Based on my testing (I have not dug through the source yet) this algorithm is tweaked slightly to pretend that the end, but not the start, is extended by one line, so that there's always a conflict if both sides add lines at the same position. (We don't know which addition should happen *first*.) Also I'm not sure if I am phrasing any of this properly—it really helps to convert it to a detailed algorithm, or study the one that's in there (I believe Git adopted the RCS merge algorithm so Tichy's work probably applies).

Comment: Thanks, what you write makes sense. It certainly explains why I sometimes get "obvious" false positives. (Arguably, such things should be documented somewhere outside of the sources...).

Comment: Also, I could try to improve my description of the patience diff algorithm. At its heart it's about comparing / locating *unique* lines (but uniqueness is per-"sub-box", so I find it hard to describe this).

Comment: Thanks for your insight, and for writing a book about it! (Even though it turns out to have nothing to do with the issue at hand.)

Answer (score 0):

as you say, this properly creates a conflicts when you try to reproduce it in isolation.

My best guess at this point is the developper of one of your branches merged the other developper branches into its own and resolved the conflict by deleting the second class definition.

Comment: No, there were no merge of either branch into the other.